# How to use google lens to scan business cards and save the fields in salesforce lead and contact objects?

Tags: contact, leads, lead-conversion, google, google-apps

I am trying to understand how the Google lens for card scanner works? If there is a way to implement that which Salesforce.  For example if you scan a card from mobile using Google lens card scanner can that be synced with Salesforce as a lead or contact.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to read business cards automaticallly and store the info in to Salesforce Objects. For that you can use the [OCR feature](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) offered by Google Cloud Vision API.

The Vision API can detect and extract text from images. There are two annotation features that support optical character recognition (OCR):

- TEXT_DETECTION detects and extracts text from any image. For example,
  a photograph might contain a street sign or traffic sign. The JSON
  includes the entire extracted string, as well as individual words,
  and their bounding boxes.

[image]

DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION also extracts text from an image, but the
   response is optimized for dense text and documents. The JSON includes
   page, block, paragraph, word, and break information.

[image]

Source : - https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr